# Tomcat error HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, html, css, tomcat, servlets

This is my jsp page

```
<html>
<head>

 <link rel = "stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
<title>Login Page</title> </head>


 <body>
    <div class ="RegWrap">
        <div class ="Set">    
<form name="actionForm" action="Connecter" method ="Get">
<table>

<tr><td>Enter your Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your Password: </td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="login"> </td></tr>
</table>
</form>


       </div>  
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Connecter class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;`



public class Connecter extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
   response.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   String n=request.getParameter("userName");           
   String p=request.getParameter("password");
            if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcom");
            rd.forward(request,response);`
   }

   else {
            out.print("Sorry username or password error");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Sign up.jsp");
            rd.include(request,response);
   }

        out.close();
    }`
```

This is my Welcome page

```
import java.io.IOException;`
import java.io.PrintWriter;`
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;`
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class welcom extends HttpServlet {
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String n=request.getParameter("userName");
 out.print("Welcome "+n);
    out.close();
}

}
}
```

This is my Dao page

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class LoginDao {

public static boolean validate(String userName,String password){
boolean status=false;

try {
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");        
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306  /autolube","root","mehar");
  PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
   ("select * from person where userName=?and password=?");


    ps.setString(1,userName);
    ps.setString(2,password);`ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    status=rs.next();`}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);
 }
return status;
}
}
```

Comment: Whats the url that you tried ?

Comment: i just compile my jsp page which is a startup page

Comment: can you paste your error stacktrace ?

Comment: please help me my project deploy well jsp page run i enter user name password but when submit then such error occur thanx.

Comment: i cant uderstand what u mean by stacktrace ?

Comment: show us the web.xml file. What servlet mapping you have done ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/FinalProject/Connecter?userName=iqbal&password=abc

Comment: sir i post again my web.xml file i tried edit but could not post please look it thanx

Answer (score 1):

In your servlet add the below line. As I commented I think its a problem with web.xml. If you are using servlet 3.0 you can use the below ammotation or map in web.xml.

```
@WebServlet("/Connecter")
public class Connecter extends HttpServlet
```

Answer (score -2):

if url-pattern is /Connector then add /Connector in your form tag of index.html.