# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, html, servlets

```
   <form method="post"    action="RegisterServletPath">

    Name:<input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Email Id:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Language: <select name="language">
        <option>Hindi</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>French</option>
    </select> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

after submitting the form the following error occur 
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
here is my java class. i have defined only post method and called post method in html form

```
   public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String n = request.getParameter("userName");
            String p = request.getParameter("password");
            String e = request.getParameter("email");
            String c = request.getParameter("language");

            try {

                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

                Connection con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/eclipse/register.accdb","","");

                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into USERDETAILS values(?,?,?,?)");

                ps.setString(1, n);
                ps.setString(2, p);
                ps.setString(3, e);
                ps.setString(4, c);

                int i= ps.executeUpdate();
                if (i > 0) {
                     out.print("You are successfully registered...");   
                }
            }
            //... not relevant here
        }
    }

web.xml 


<display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>   
<servlet>
<servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.venkatesh.Servlet.RegisterServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/RegisterServletPath</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is control even reaching your RegisterServlet? Try adding some print statements to confirm that.

Comment: yes the control does not reach RegisterServlet @Jitendra

Comment: Well then show us your web.xml configuration where you're mapping your URLs to Controllers.

Comment: And... what is the URL? What are you doing to get that exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783879/tomcat-error-http-status-405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url

Comment: i have added get method it executes

Answer (score -1):

add the rest of the servlet code, I think you are either using `doGet` method and calling `super.doGet` from it, or not using `doGet` but unfortunatly the `doGet` method in `HttpServlet` is being called.

Here comes another problem! from where the `doGet` method in either case is being called?

If you can't find where, then try adding

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

this should solve the problem, if it doesn't then let me know if all my assumptions are wrong.